# Issue with Calendar calculation that spans 2 calendar years

Tags: java, calendar

I'm using a method that calculates the next Monday from a given date string.

```
public static String getStartOfNextWeek(String DATE){

String format = "dd.MM.yyyy";SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(format);

Date date = null;
try {
date = df.parse(DATE);
} catch (ParseException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}

Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();

cal.setTime(date);
int week = cal.get(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR);
int year = cal.get(Calendar.YEAR);

Calendar calendar = new GregorianCalendar();
calendar.clear(); 
calendar.set(Calendar.YEAR, year);
calendar.set(Calendar.WEEK_OF_YEAR, week);

//add 8 days to get next weeks Monday

calendar.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, 8);

Date startDate = calendar.getTime();

SimpleDateFormat df2 = new SimpleDateFormat("dd.MM.yyyy");

String start = df2.format(startDate);

return start;
```

This work perfectly fine over a single calendar year, but when I'm passing a value that spans two calendar years problems arise.

For example:

```
input: 15.12.2014
output: 22.12.2014 CORRECT
input: 22.12.2014
output: 29.12.2014 CORRECT
input: 29.12.2014
output: 6.1.2014 INCORRECT
```

I realize where the mistake is located, since it takes WEEK_OF_YEAR as "1", but YEAR as "2014", so the output is technically correct. Just wrong for my purpose.

How would i best tell the calendar object that i want the next monday in week 1, but 2015?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Get first Monday after certain date?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7565356/get-first-monday-after-certain-date) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9612328/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/10072914/642706) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/26754164/642706) and many others. Tip: Joda-Time.

Comment: The day-of-month is wrong also, not just the year, in your output. The first Monday following 2014-12-29 is 2015-01-05 (not the 6th).

Comment: Basil, look closely - it returns 6.1.**2014** as the next Monday from 29.12.2014, which actually **is** incorrect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project is now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), with the team advising migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes. This Answer is left intact as history. See [my newer Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48697062/642706).

## Joda-Time

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) library, version 2.5, gets the correct answer. And gets it more easily.

```
// Parse input string.
String input = "29.12.2014";
DateTimeFormatter formatter = DateTimeFormat.forPattern( "dd.MM.yyyy" );
LocalDate inputLocalDate = formatter.parseLocalDate( input );

// Find desired Monday.
LocalDate possibleMonday = inputLocalDate.withDayOfWeek( DateTimeConstants.MONDAY ); 

// The possible Monday could be past, present, or future of our input date. Adjust as needed.
LocalDate desiredMonday = null;
if ( possibleMonday.isBefore( inputLocalDate ) || possibleMonday.isEqual( inputLocalDate ) ) {
    desiredMonday = possibleMonday.plusWeeks( 1 ); // If the possible Monday is past or present, add a week to get *next* Monday.
} else {
    desiredMonday = possibleMonday;  // If the possible Monday is future, use it.
}

String output = formatter.print( desiredMonday );
```

Dump to console.

```
System.out.println( "input : " + input );
System.out.println( "inputLocalDate : " + inputLocalDate );
System.out.println( "desiredMonday : " + desiredMonday );
System.out.println( "output : " + output );
```

When run.

```
input : 29.12.2014
inputLocalDate : 2014-12-29
desiredMonday : 2015-01-05
output : 05.01.2015
```

Comment: great, thanks, just what I was looking for. Simple and comprehensive.

Answer (score 0):

There's something weird when combining Date and Calender, when it comes to parsing dates, using only Calender it works great;

```
    String[] dt = dateStr.split("\\.");
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(Integer.parseInt(dt[2]), (Integer.parseInt(dt[1])-1), Integer.parseInt(dt[0]));
    cal.setFirstDayOfWeek(Calendar.MONDAY);
    cal.clear(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK);
    cal.add(Calendar.DATE, 7);
    System.out.println(cal.get(Calendar.YEAR) + "." + (cal.get(Calendar.MONTH)+1) + "." + cal.get(Calendar.DATE));
```

Edit: You have to subtract 1 from the month, since calendar expects the months to range from 0 to 11.
      (*Calendar.JANUARY == 0*) //true

Answer (score 0):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDate.parse( 
    "29.12.2014" ,
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" )
).with(
    TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY )
)
```

> 2015-01-05

## java.time

The modern approach  uses the *java.time* classes.

```
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "dd.MM.uuuu" )
LocalDate ld = LocalDate.parse( "29.12.2014" , f ) ;
```

To move to another date, use a `TemporalAdjuster` implementation found in the `TemporalAdjusters` class. Specify the desired day-of-week with `DayOfWeek` enum object. No problem crossing end-of-year/start-of-year.

```
LocalDate followingMonday = ld.with( TemporalAdjusters.next( DayOfWeek.MONDAY ) ) ;
```

If you want to use the current date if it is a Monday, use `TemporalAdjusters.nextOrSame`.

Similar methods provide for *previous* day-of-week, as well: `previous` & `previousOrSame`.

---

## About *java.time*

The [*java.time*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [*Joda-Time*](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [*Oracle Tutorial*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - Later versions of Android bundle implementations of the java.time classes.
  - For earlier Android, the [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above). See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).